# git clone http repo with fatal: repository not found

Tags: git, http, clone

My repository is a STASH and the command and error is as below:

```
> git clone http://username@repo-server-host:7990/scm/myproj.git
Cloning into 'myproj'...
fatal: repository 'http://username@repo-server-host:7990/scm/myproj.git/' not found
```

1. This command works on my colleague's laptop, both windows and Linux
2. "git clone ssh:....." works on my laptop, which is windows
3. try to open the repo url from local chrome and it jumps to the stash page after username/password input
4. ping the repo-server-host works on my laptop
5. shutdown the local firewall, still not working

Is there any other suggestions?

Thanks in adv.

Comment: Do you have any http proxies on your CLI tool ?

Comment: @JuniorDev you're correct. I forget to unset it. Thanks for the reminding.